# How can I get the ID of an FireStore Document, if i know the value of one field? (In Swift)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm programming in Swift and I have a little problem.

I wondered how I can get the ID of an Document, if I have the the value for a field in it.

Little example:

```
document_x -> name: x, number: 5

document_y -> name: y, number: 2

document_z -> name: z, number 16
```

And now I know that I want the ID of the document, which has the name: z (in this case document_z)

Is this possible?

Comment: Btw: Im using Swift

Comment: It's a huge problem in Firebase.  **One common solution is to actually store the document ID, as a field, in the document!!**  So whenever you make a new document (example, add a user) you actually get the doc id and add it in there as a field, perhaps named "thisDocId" !

Answer (score 2):

To find the document(s) matching a specific value in a field you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). Something like this:

```
let query = collectionRef.whereField("name", isEqualTo: "z")
query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem some months back.fire base was generating  random doc id because of not giving specific id.
there are two approaches to this:
first one : this is how i found my doc id w.r.t to string i have given in it

```
    private func GetFireBaseID(_ ComingToBeDel : String , completion:@escaping(String) -> ()) {
        db.collection(FireBaseConstant.ProjectCollectioName).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let currentdata = document.data()
                    if let currenttitle  = currentdata[FireBaseConstant.ProjectVC.ProjectName] as? String {
                        if currenttitle == ComingToBeDel {
                            completion(document.documentID)
                            break
                            
                        }else {
                            completion("")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

caller is like this

```
            GetFireBaseID(filterobj[index].ProjectTitle) { (returnid) in
                if returnid.count > 0 {
                    db.collection(FireBaseConstant.ProjectCollectioName).document(returnid).updateData([
                        FireBaseConstant.ProjectVC.ProjectName : string
                    ])
                }else {
                    print("couldnt find your file")
                }
            }
```

second method can be using whereField filtered queries.for that please consult following link.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries